# What spring artifact to depend upon for just creating beans?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Some smaller modules in my project only create a config class and expose some beans.
The dependency on Spring classes is really just `@Bean`, `@Autowired`, `@Configuration`, `@Service`.

Currently in my gradle file, to include these dependencies, I do:

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
```

This obviously pulls in a ton of unwanted stuff.

What artifact should I depend upon to pull in the most minimal amount of libraries to satisfy the above dependency on 4 classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need `spring-core`, `spring-context`, and `spring-beans` (which have dependencies on other libraries too).

[`spring-context`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.0.RELEASE) should pull in everything you need.